# How to make a message print when off turn on in Java

Tags: java, class, methods

I am trying to make an elevator program where if the elevator is in an off state and it turns on it prints out a message. I am using a static method for this, as I have to use a static method for this. I have tried a few ways to make this happen but the closest I have gotten is it printing out whenever the power = true.

Here is my code:

```
private static boolean powerOn = true;

    //power on/off
    public static void setPowerState() {
    powerOn = !powerOn;
    }

    //get the power state and print the message
    public static void getPowerState(boolean powerOn) {
  if (powerOn == true){
              System.out.println("Power Reinstated");
           }
    }
```

Here is the code in a seperate class to print out the message and turn on and off the power:

```
`//turn power off
Elevator.setPowerState();

//set power to on again
        Elevator.setPowerState();
        
//see if the message prints out a second time
    Elevator.getPowerState(true);
    Elevator.getPowerState(true);
```

I have tried an if statement as you can see but all that is doing is printint out the message whenever I call the method. I think I need to change the getPowerState method I have but I am not sure how. Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: In getPowerState, print a message if powerOn is not true.  (By the way, a method called getThing that does not get the Thing but merely prints out the state of the Thing is misnamed)

Comment: Because the `powerOn` boolean variable is a *public static* class member variable, it is global to the entire class and accessible to all other classes. **togglePowerState()** would indeed be a better name for the `setPowerState()` method since this is exactly what it's doing...toggling. Because `powerOn` is global, it should not be passed as as argument to the `getPowerState()` method since that variable would be a local variable to the method **only** and would have nothing to do with the global variable. Remove that parameter declaration from the `getPowerState()` method signature.

Comment: I see you created a new account after you've deleted your old one (probably due to a question ban). You know, SO is not a free tutoring site and your questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75617066/turning-on-and-off-checking-if-it-is-on-or-off-and-printing-a-message-when-off),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75631902/i-need-to-use-a-method-with-this-to-remove-people-from-an-elevator-program),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75628722/using-a-method-to-add-people-in-an-elevator-program) were downvoted because they didn't show much effort. [cont.]...

Comment: ...[cont.] Also, don't ask a question for every single step in your homework. Try to solve it at least once on your own. Ask your class mates and professor if 
you have questions regarding your task. There's another user with a suspiciously 
similar [task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75644813/using-a-constructor-to-set-a-number-back-to-1-when-it-goes-over-a-certain-number), so if this really is the same task, you could work together. BTW, creating a new account to circumvent the question ban is highly discouraged.

Comment: And a 4th one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75644813/using-a-constructor-to-set-a-number-back-to-1-when-it-goes-over-a-certain-number) @QBrute

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no need for a new method for this. Simply in your `setPowerState()` method (which I would rename to `togglePowerState()` since this isn't a true "setter" method), add an if block at the end that prints your message if the power has been turned on:

```
// toggle power on/off  -- note method name has been changed
public static void togglePower() {
    powerOn = !powerOn;
    if (powerOn) {
        System.out.println("The power has been turned on");
    }
}
```

The advantage here is that the if block is called whenever the power state is toggled by this method. Note that this won't work if you can change your power state by other means, such as with a public field or a separate true "setter" method. If this is possible, then you will likely need to make powerState a "bound property" and use Java bean's PropertyChangeSupport along with a PropertyChangeListener, something which is probably over-kill for this assignment.

I would be remiss if I didn't mention the evils of over-use of static methods and fields, and while it may be a requirement of your project to use statics for this, in the long run, you likely wouldn't.

So, if this were my project, I'd make powerOn a private *instance* field:

```
private boolean powerOn = false;

public boolean ispowerOn() {
    return powerOn;
}
```

and I'd make it a "bound property" using the tools mentioned above:

```
// constant String to indicate which property we are listening to
public static final String POWER_ON = "power on";

// prop change support: notifies listeners of changes in property
private PropertyChangeSupport support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

// our bound property
private boolean powerOn = false;

public boolean ispowerOn() {
    return powerOn;
}

// in the setter, notify any listeners by firing the support object
public void setpowerOn(boolean powerOn) {
    boolean oldValue = this.powerOn;
    boolean newValue = powerOn;
    this.powerOn = powerOn;
    support.firePropertyChange(POWER_ON, oldValue, newValue);
}

public void togglePower() {
    setpowerOn(!powerOn);  // this triggers the prop chng support
}
```

and we'd have to allow outside classes the ability to add/remove property change listeners:

```
public void addPowerChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pcListener) {
    support.addPropertyChangeListener(POWER_ON, pcListener);
}

public void removePowerChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pcListener) {
    support.removePropertyChangeListener(pcListener);
}
```

The whole thing could look like:

```
public class Elevator {
    // constant String to indicate which property we are listening to
    public static final String POWER_ON = "power on";

    // prop change support: notifies listeners of changes in property
    private PropertyChangeSupport support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    // our bound property
    private boolean powerOn = false;

    public boolean ispowerOn() {
        return powerOn;
    }

    // in the setter, notify any listeners by firing the support object
    public void setpowerOn(boolean powerOn) {
        boolean oldValue = this.powerOn;
        boolean newValue = powerOn;
        this.powerOn = powerOn;
        support.firePropertyChange(POWER_ON, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public void togglePower() {
        setpowerOn(!powerOn);  // this triggers the prop chng support
    }
    
    public void addPowerChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pcListener) {
        support.addPropertyChangeListener(POWER_ON, pcListener);
    }
    
    public void removePowerChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pcListener) {
        support.removePropertyChangeListener(pcListener);
    }
}
```

Then an outside class could easily add a property change listener, one that is notified whenever the powerOn property changes:

```
Elevator elevator = new Elevator();
elevator.addPowerChangeListener(pcEvent -> {
    if (elevator.ispowerOn()) {
        // fired if the power is on
        System.out.println("The power is ON!");
    } else {
        // if you want output for when the power switches off
    }
});
```

A complete testing class could look like:

```
// imports
public class TestElevator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Elevator elevator = new Elevator();
        elevator.addPowerChangeListener(pcEvent -> {
            if (elevator.ispowerOn()) {
                // fired if the power is on
                System.out.println("The power is ON!");
            } else {
                // if you want output for when the power switches off
            }
        });
        
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        boolean keepGoing = true;
        while (keepGoing) {
            System.out.print("Enter \"on\" to turn on power, \"off\" to turn it off, \"toggle\" to toggle it, and \"quit\" to quit: ");
            String input = scan.nextLine();
            switch (input.toLowerCase()) {
            case "on":
                elevator.setpowerOn(true);
                break;
            case "off":
                elevator.setpowerOn(false);
                break;
            case "toggle":
                elevator.togglePower();
                break;
            case "quit":
                keepGoing = false;
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, try again");
                break;
            }
        }        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a method called `setPowerState` suggests that you will set the power state to a value, so it should look like this:

```
    //power on/off
    public static void setPowerState(boolean po) {
        powerOn = po;
    }
```

You can also implement a toggler, but then you should name it `togglePowerState` and it should look like this:

```
    //power on/off
    public static void togglePowerState() {
        setPowerState(!getPowerState());
    }
```

But, in order to have that, we need to implement a proper getter, like this:

```
    public static boolean getPowerState() {
        return powerState;
    }
```

Notice that here we do not have a print, because you need to separate the logic from the UI/CLI, to save yourself from large headaches later. So, if you want to print the value, you can try it like this:

```
if (getPowerState()) {
    System.out.println("Power Reinstated");
}
```

Also, here we only had `static` methods, which are class-level. You may consider removing the `static` keyword, so they will be instance-level and that would allow your class to control the state of as many elevators as you want instead of a single one.